# Laravel - Get value from an object

Tags: php, laravel

I have an PHP object coming back from an API. The following is dd($token):

```
OAuth2AccessToken {#559 ▼
  -accessTokenKey: "eyJlbmMiOiJBMTI4Q0JDLUhTMjU2IiwiYWxn8F2X3MBCZYY1g7Do66LIK"
  -tokenType: "bearer"
  -refresh_token: "Q01156b975259zYyAN03aS8lf6YfRcYFK26w2xCvPu75zf0B9F"
  -accessTokenExpiresAt: 1559257067
  -refreshTokenExpiresAt: 1567975300
  -accessTokenValidationPeriod: 3600
  -refreshTokenValidationPeriod: 8751833
  -clientID: "Q06uUceuP2dpIJVmmqbWztlZ73dtb9Qd2shjbiKhkGt7lsimR"
  -clientSecret: "RD0fS7xiRNsmbwSBBXvgU3wsqtyNPy63DfoGq2"
  -realmID: "1385384240"
  -baseURL: "https://quickbooks.api.intuit.com/"
}
```

How do I get the key "accessTokenKey" into a variable?

I have tried:

```
$token->accessTokenKey;
```

or

```
$token['accessTokenKey'];
```

I get error "Cannot access private property"

Comment: `$access = $token->getAccessToken()`

Comment: Also, if you have a decent IDE, it will give you each public properties and methods of the object you're trying to access.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, is a private propety. This propety cannot be called outside from Model/Class, because its private, can be only access by Class. You need to use some function to get this. Maybe you can get with
$token->getAccessToken(). I should you learn more about OOP Concepts. In very essential in Laravel.

`public scope` to make that variable/function available from anywhere, other classes and instances of the object.

`private scope` when you want your variable/function to be visible in its own class only.

`protected scope` when you want to make your variable/function visible in all classes that extend current class including the parent class.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `\ReflectionClass` class

```
public function get_private_attribute_of($object, $property)
{
    $reflection = new \ReflectionClass($object);
    $property = $reflection->getProperty($property);
    $property->setAccessible(true);
    return $property->getValue($object);
}
```

usage:

```
get_private_attribute_of($token, 'accessTokenKey');
```

or can use `dd(get_class_methods($object))` for now all available methods name and select needed method