# How get properties from object in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am beginner in Laravel. I use Laravel 5.8 in my project.

I have this object:

```
NominatimAddress {#1146 ▼
  -attribution: "Data © OpenStreetMap contributors, ODbL 1.0. https://osm.org/copyright"
  -category: "building"
  -displayName: "99, 9 Maja, Janowo, Olsztyn, powiat pomorski, pomorskie, "
  -osmType: "way"
  -osmId: 142789154
  -type: "yes"
  -coordinates: Coordinates {#1147 ▼
    -latitude: 51.51171143
    -longitude: 11.4023121
  }
  -bounds: Bounds {#1148 ▶}
  -adminLevels: AdminLevelCollection {#1149 ▶}
  -country: Country {#1152 ▶}
  -timezone: null
  -providedBy: "nominatim"
}
```

How can I get latitude and longitude from this object?

Comment: just like from any object, access with `->`. `$object->coordinates->latitude`

Comment: Undefined property: Geocoder\Provider\Nominatim\Model\NominatimAddress::$coordinates - I have this error

Comment: This is a private property. look this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56386215/laravel-get-value-from-an-object/56386930#56386930

Comment: I agree with @Davit that those properties are `protected` or `private`, hence not accessible from the outside. Since you didn't include what libraries are you using in the question, I'm gonna venture a guess and say that you try `$object->coordinates->getLatitude()` and `$object->coordinates->getLongitude()` as most of the time private properties that need access are hidden behind getters and setters. But as a general rule of thumb please try to include as much information in your question as you can, because it helps you get faster and more accurate answers.

Comment: Actually after a minute of googling I think this is the class that has the coordinates implementation https://github.com/geocoder-php/Geocoder/blob/master/src/Common/Model/Coordinates.php.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I can see, you are using [Geocoder](https://github.com/geocoder-php/Geocoder) library. So, `NominatimAddress` extends `Address`, which have following method:

```
public function getCoordinates()
{
    return $this->coordinates;
}
```

And as Bogdan commented, coordinates are incapsulated into [Coordinates](https://github.com/geocoder-php/Geocoder/blob/master/src/Common/Model/Coordinates.php) class, which has accessors for latitude and longitude.

Then you can try:

```
$lat = $object->getCoordinates()->getLatitude();
$lon = $object->getCoordinates()->getLongitude();
```

Answer (score 0):

Accessing attribute in Laravel Eloquent Model is pretty easy. It's same as accessing stdClass object's attributes.

Let's say you have variable `$object` that holds your object. You will access longitude and latitude attributes with:

```
$lat = $object->coordinates->latitude;
```

Comment: This is not working :( I have error: Undefined property: Geocoder\Provider\Nominatim\Model\NominatimAddress::$coordinates

Comment: Please edit your answer with piece of code where you're trying to access attribute, your "use" piece of code and other relevant lines so I can edit my answer accordingly.

Answer (score -1):

```
$lat = $object->coordinates->latitude;
$long = $object->coordinates->longitude;
```